# How to access functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    function mmm(x){
        var val= [10,20,30];
        return val;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function my(){
        var va= mmm();
        var b= va[1];
        document.write(b);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

there is a mistake in the above code, output is not generated. What I need is to display contents of 'val' of 'mmm(x)' function inside 'my()' function using document.write().

The two functions should be in different script tags. What are the changes do I need to make?

Comment: Is it because you're not calling `my()`? Because it sure [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/fVnAz/) when I call my() right after.

Comment: Also, it doesn't really matter that mmm is accepting parameters, because it's not using any anyways. The only issue would be when you try to minify the JS, some programs might raise an error about not sending the proper amount of arguments to a function. In my testing, it worked without removing the `x`, but if you're not using it, you might as well remove it.

Comment: Lol ... Is that even a question... Only if I had the power to close this..

Comment: Looks like guys are using stackoverflow to solve school assignment ;-)

Comment: good try  @MarmiK. But actually I encountered this problem in my job oriented project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not calling `my` function anywhere.

Try this.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function mmm(x){
var val= [10,20,30];
return val;
}
</script>

<script>
function my(){
var va= mmm(1);
var b= va[1];
document.write(b);
}
</script>
</body>
<button onclick="my()">click</button>
</html>
```

What I have done here I have a page having a button, and when you will click on that button, it will call that `my` function, and you will get `20` on your page.

Comment: function mmm(x) having parameters

Comment: @SujithKarivelil any way that is not being used, updated my answer.

Comment: @ Mritunjay : that's right , but the actual and formal arguments need to match in function call

Comment: thanks. x is not required, i had used it in other code. so...

Answer (score -1):

You are not calling the function `my`

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mmm(x){
var val= [10,20,30];
return val;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function my(){
var va= mmm();
var b= va[1];
document.write(b);
}

my();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<script>
function mmm(){ //unwanted parameter is removed
var val= [10,20,30];
return val;
}
</script>
<script>
function my(){
var va= mmm();
var b= va[1];
document.write(b);
}
my();//calling method here
</script>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DxwA5/)

Comment: function mmm(x) having parameters

Comment: You can call it without parameter and its tested. Op not using that parameter in function not its not necessary.

Comment: that's right , but the actual and formal arguments need to match in function call –

Comment: OP should understand this.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil That is incorrect. [JavaScript does not enforce argument lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18856999). That is, only API level functions will restrict that, primarily native API functions provided by the browser. But in this case, there is no problem calling mmm with no parameters. In fact, you can call it with more, and you will still be able to access additional parameters via the arguments object. There's even an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/arity) designed to force parameters because JavaScript does not do it on its own.